# Does Wondershare still play videos or is it discontinued?

Tags: video

When I go to [WonderShare's player page it says "discontinued" on it it](https://www.wondershare.com/video-player/).

Does that mean their free player is discontinued, but the Ultimate version still plays videos, or does that mean that the video playback feature of the software has been removed in all versions?

When I look at their main page their feature list does seem to mention playing videos as a feature:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wondershare is junk. They often spam forums with fake posts advertising their software. You don't see it here often because they are well known to the anti-spam measures. It looks to be from China and is one of many such clones (adoreshare, brorsoft, idealshare, pavtube, xilisoft, etc) possibly owned by the same group. I wouldn't trust any of them.

Many of their products are just a GUI for `ffmpeg` and other free software, but they don't distribute it in accordance to the FFmpeg license, so they are in violation of the license (not that they give a damn).

Here's a running tally of some of these clowns:

[FFmpeg: Spamming GPL license violators](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3988)

Answer (score 0):

Wondershare may be moving out of the video playing industry as it may not be a high revenue source, plus this industry has many better or equivalent products (VLC, Quicktime, etc)

Their ultimate version of their product doesn't have a "real" video player, meaning there isn't a feature that is clearly for video playing. You can look at video's from the video converter (from the edit video function) but it isn't designed for video playing.

Wondershare isn't completely moving out of this industry though, they have now currently expanded to the [Android video playing](https://www.wondershare.com/video-player/android-media-player.html) market which may be one that is going to stay. So they haven't completely removed this feature.